# Get Facebook Logged in User Details in my web page

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've created a facebook page and added a call-to-action button that redirects to my web page. Now i want to pre-populate the logged in facebook user name and email in my web page form. **How can i achieve this ??** I'm creating my web page using Codeigniter PHP framework.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi